# Undocumented System Procedure 'sp_MSforeachtable' and the @whereand parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, system-procedures

I'm attempting to use [the undocumented system procedure `sp_MSforeachtable`](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm). But I need to restrict the affected tables to those that start with "smp" and that are in the "`dbo`" schema. I was able to find how to find procedures that start with "smp". I simply do:

```
sp_MSforeachtable @command1=' print ''?''', @whereand=' and name like ''smp%''  '
```

but how do I filter for a given schema using the `@whereand` parameter?

**UPDATE**: I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
sp_MSforeachtable @command1=' print ''?''', @whereand=' and name like ''smp%'' and Left(''?'', 5)=''[dbo]'' '
```

**Update 2**: I'm running on SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Ok, finally got it for SQL 2000. please see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update for SQL2000:

```
declare @s nvarchar(1000)
set @s = ' and uid = ' + convert(nvarchar, user_id('my_schema'))
exec sp_msforeachtable @command1='print ''?''', @whereand = @s
```

Comment: 1st one, Error message that says: 'SCHEMA_NAME' is not a recognized function name.

2nd one, I get an error when concatinating and on top of that a simple select like what follows gives me: 'SCHEMA_ID' is not a recognized function name. - select ' and name like ''smp%'' AND schema_id = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SCHEMA_ID('dbo') )

Answer (score 3):

This should works in SQL Server 2000 (can't test now):

```
@whereand = '
  AND name like ''smp%'' AND
  OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(''name''), ''OwnerID'') = USER_ID(''dbo'')'
```

Use [OBJECTPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276849(SQL.80).aspx) to find the schema owner id.

Edit: OK, tested it on a SQL 2000 box:

```
@whereand = ' AND name LIKE ''smp%'' AND uid = 1'
OR
@whereand = ' AND name LIKE ''smp%'' AND USER_ID(''dbo'')'
```

I could not get OBJECTPROPERTY to work

Comment: Hypothetically, it should work -- but it doesn't...  I'm honestly not sure why but I ended up with no results. (And I did replace the "name" with ?

Comment: What does OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(''name''), ''OwnerID'') in the query? NULL? 1?

Comment: I think he meant: OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(''?'')  where the question mark is the @replacechar.  If you are asking what that will resolve to -- it resolves to 1 assuming that I the correct dbo.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://avinashkt.blogspot.com/2008/05/useful-operations-with-spmsforeachtable.html):

```
---------------------
--Drop table of particular shcemaID/shemaName and with name starting with 'Temp_'
Exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = "DROP TABLE ? PRINT '? dropped'"
    ,@whereand = "and uid = (SELECT schema_id FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'dbo')
                  and o.name LIKE 'Temp_%'"
---------------------
```

Comment: I had saw that from google searching. I get: Invalid object name 'sys.schemas'. I figure this is because I'm running on SQL server 2000.

Comment: SQL 2000 doesn't have SCHEMAS, they have OWNERS.

Answer (score 0):

This verion works in Sql Server 2005:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable
    @command1=' print ''?''',
    @whereand=' and schema_name(schema_id) = ''dbo'' '
```

Not exactly sure for Sql Server 2000, but this version might work:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable
    @command1=' print ''?''',
    @whereand=' and user_name(uid) = ''dbo'' '
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked in 2008 R2

@whereand='and uid = (SELECT schema_id FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = ''dbo'') and o.name LIKE ''TEMP_%'''